# Azure Powershell script returns "SubscriptionRequestsThrottled" error message

Tags: powershell, azure

I have written a script to automate provisioning a series of Azure VMs configured in its own virtual network and AD domain for testing.
Midway thru testing the script, the error message occurs as:
`SubscriptionRequestsThrottled: Number of read requests for subscription 'xxx-...' exceeded the limit of '15000' for time interval '01:00:00'`

This error appears intermittently at different steps in the script so I'm assuming it is indeed a throttling issue. My question is if there is a way to configure the limit and time-interval values so that this script can execute swiftly without these errors occurring?

Answer (score 0):

The total request rate limit for a storage account is 20,000 IOPS. If a virtual machine utilizes the maximum IOPS per disk, then to avoid possible throttling, ensure that the total IOPS across all of the virtual machines' VHDs does not exceed the storage account limit (20,000 IOPS).

You can roughly calculate the number of highly utilized disks supported by a single storage account based on the transaction limit. For example, for a Basic Tier VM, the maximum number of highly utilized disks is about 66 (20,000/300 IOPS per disk), and for a Standard Tier VM, it is about 40 (20,000/500 IOPS per disk). However, note that the storage account can support a larger number of disks if they are not all highly utilized at the same time.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/ for more information.